# Insert values into SQLite Database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Is there an easier way I can insert data in a table in SQLite? What I need is to insert State_ID and State_Name in Table tblState. Since there are a lot of State in US, is there another way I can use instead of this:

```
String ROW1 = "INSERT INTO tblState VALUES (1,'Alabama')";
String ROW2 = "INSERT INTO tblState VALUES (2,'Alaska')";
String ROW3 = "INSERT INTO tblState VALUES (3,'California')";
db.execSQL(ROW1);
db.execSQL(ROW2);
db.execSQL(ROW3);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can try like this ...Have state in an array. Execute a single insert statement inside for loop until this state array finish..

Comment: You can concatenate all the `INSERT` in one string, then execute one `db.execSQL`

Comment: Subburaj how will i do that? sorry i'm just new in doing this. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for this..

```
String state[] = { "state1" , "state2",.............};
    int id=1;
    for(int i=0;i<state.length;i++)
    {
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tblState VALUES (id,state[i])");
    id++;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Subburaj!Great help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
String ALLROWS = "INSERT INTO tblState"
    + "SELECT 1 AS 'State_ID', 'Alabama' AS 'State_Name'"
    + "UNION SELECT 2 AS 'State_ID', 'Alaska' AS 'State_Name'"
    + "UNION SELECT 3 AS 'State_ID', 'California' AS 'State_Name'";

db.execSQL(ALLROWS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ContentValues` for each of the rows you want to insert:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put('State_ID', 1);
values.put('State_Name', "Alabama");
```

and then use `db.insert("tblState", null, values)` to insert the row. You can write a method to construct your ContentValues:

```
public ContentValues method(int id, String name) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put('State_ID', id);
    values.put('State_Name', name);
}
```

Your code will be:

```
db.insert("tblState", null, method(1, "Alabama"));
db.insert("tblState", null, method(2, "Alaska"));
db.insert("tblState", null, method(3, "California"));
```

Or just loop through all the states...